# Elasticsearch cross cluster replication - unable to open any proxy connections

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Elasticsearch version: 7.15

We have 2 separated ELK clusters (3 nodes each) deployed in 2 different locations in Openshift.
To deploy we are using a helm (no operator yet).
We enabled the CCR between them. The CCR connection is going through a F5 LoadBalancer.
The cluster is configured with security and TSL enabled.

The cross cluster replication is working fine but sometimes we see the following exception:

```
 [2021-11-19T14:16:58,628][WARN ][o.e.t.TcpTransport ] [elasticsearch-master-0] exception caught on transport layer 
 [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:47822, remoteAddress=elk-master.local.net/YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:443, profile=default}], closing connection

 io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

 [2021-11-19T14:16:58,629][WARN ][o.e.x.c.a.ShardFollowNodeTask] [elasticsearch-master-0] shard follow task encounter non-retryable error

 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open any proxy connections to remote cluster [elasticsearch-cluster-2]
```

Now we do not know exactly what is going on since the CCR before this exception was working fine.
Maybe the F5 LB sometimes closes the connections or maybe sometime we have some network issue, we are still investigating.
However after we get that exception the CCR is broken.
To solve this issue we just have to restart the POD without ANY modification and the CCR starts to work again:

```
[2021-11-22T10:24:31,168][INFO ][o.e.x.c.a.ShardFollowTasksExecutor] [elasticsearch-master-0] [myindex-2021.11.18-000001][0] Starting to track leader shard [myindex-2021.11.18-000001][0]

[2021-11-22T10:24:31,558][INFO ][o.e.x.c.a.ShardFollowNodeTask] [elasticsearch-master-0] [myindex-2021.11.18-000001][0] following leader shard [myindex-2021.11.18-000001][0], follower global checkpoint=[-1], mapping version=[2], settings version=[1], aliases version=[1]
```

The configuration of our pods and the TSL configuration is ok since we can replicate the indexes across the clusters, but sometimes we see that issue and it seems that the only way to solve it is to restart a master pod.

Comment: can you remove the load balancer? because it's not possible that Elasticsearch can suddenly change tls settings, and so it's likely that causing the issue

Comment: @MarkWalkom I think as well that is the load balancer that sometimes it drops the connections and answer with it's own certificate which is wrong. Unfortunately I cannot remove it since I am in Openshift and I have to be resilient if an Openshift node crashes. However I think that Elasticsearch should retry to reopen the connection automatically